# how is a matrix associated with a canvas in android?

Tags: android

i was just going through the documentation given on developer.android.com and when i was going through the canvas class if i found this method named scale, so i searched for its documentation and found the following:

public void scale (float sx, float sy)
Since: API Level 1

Preconcat the current matrix with the specified scale.
Parameters
sx  The amount to scale in X
sy  The amount to scale in Y

what matrix are they talking about over here? How is the matrix associated with canvas and how does it matter if i scale my canvas or not?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Canvas makes a lot of native calls under the covers and delegates its work to GL.  I believe there is a default Matrix already associated with it.  If you want in-depth knowledge of what's happening I'd recommend looking through the [source code](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#ML2Ie1A679g/src/android/graphics/Canvas.java&q=android.graphics.Canvas%20lang%3ajava&sa=N&cd=3&ct=rc) for the graphics stuff.

Comment: could you also answer the other two questions that i have mentioned above?

Comment: The Matrix is used to transform the coordinates. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630594/html5-canvas-transformation-matrix  I think it should answer what you're looking for.